# Calling JavaScript oncontextmenu from Excel VBA

Tags: javascript, html, excel, vba, web-scraping

I am trying to call a right click menu on a web page available on Intranet. I am doing it from an Excel macro. This menu is only available when the ueser performs a right click on an element in particular table. When clicked a box with four options is displayed.
I need to perform an action that is connected to the fourth option in that menu.

I have the following references active in that macro:
VBA, MS Excel 16.0, MS Office 16.0, MS Internet Controls, Ms HTML Object Library,Ms Forms 2.0, UiAutomationClient

I have set valid references to the following HTML tags (all are tested and 100% accurate):

1. iframe
2. body
3. table(class "tabela1_small") - I have a reference to the row containing data that needs to be right clicked
4. div (id="pop")
5. span (Pokaż kalkulację )

[a piece of the HTML code of the page I am trying to automate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XKAwf.jpg)

```
    Dim IE As InternetExplorer
    Dim Document As HTMLDocument
    Dim e As IHTMLElement
    Dim f As IHTMLElement
    Dim elements2 As IHTMLElementCollection
    Dim html_span As HTMLSpanElement
    Dim html_input As HTMLInputElement
    Dim html_body As HTMLBody



    Set iframeDoc = IE.Document.frames("list").Document
    Set html_input = iframeDoc.getElementsByName("akcja")(0) 'html_input = <INPUT id=akcja type=hidden value="pokaż kalkulację " name=akcja>
    html_input.Value = "pokaż kalkulację "


    'manipulating input field
    hWnd = IE.hWnd
    SetForegroundWindow hWnd
    SendKeys "~"
    html_input.Click
    html_input.FireEvent ("oncontextmenu")
    html_input.FireEvent ("onmouseover")  

    Set html_body = iframeDoc.getElementsByTagName("body").Item(0) ' <body oncontextmenu="javascript: CoM(); return false;">

    Call IE.Document.parentWindow.execScript("parent.pokaz_kalkul(dowod.numer)", "JavaScript") 'f na objIE.Document


    'manipulate span/div elements
    Set e = iframeDoc.getElementById("dowod") ' e = <DIV id=dowod>
    Set elements2 = e.getElementsByTagName("div")
    Set f = elements2.Item(3) ' f= <SPAN onclick="javascript: parent.pokaz_kalkul(dowod.numer)">Pokaż kalkulację </SPAN>
```

(        e.Click
        f.Click

Unfortunatelly none of the fire event calls work (no error, but nothing happens). 
execScript command causes Run-time error -2147352319 (80020101).

Is there a way to simulate a right click on the table element,div or span ?
Or can this javascript parent.pokaz_kalkul(dowod.numer) be called directly without the need to click anything?

Comment: Please use the snippet tool available via [edit] to insert HTML. Don't use images. We can't copy paste those.

Comment: Did you try FireEvent "onclick" ?  Also, have you tried using selenium basic for this?

Comment: Yes, I have tried FireEvent "onclick" - nothing happens

Comment: Make the control take focus, that helps.  Also, see this https://exceldevelopmentplatform.blogspot.com/2018/01/vba-webscraping-firing-html-buttons.html and this https://exceldevelopmentplatform.blogspot.com/2018/02/vba-ie-createevent-and-dispatchevent-to.html